# My Macbook air won't go to sleep when I close the lid

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Since I have purchased my Macbookair, it has been going to sleep mode when I closed the lid and the apple logo on its lid would turn off. Randomly it started going to sleep mode after 15-30 mins later I have closed its lid and sometimes it never went to sleep. I typed "`pmset -g assertions`" in the terminal of my mac and these were the results:

```
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 117(hidd): [0x0003be5000098b76] 00:28:29 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294995445.11" 
    Timeout will fire in 119 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 331(useractivityd): [0x0003c4fb00018c32] 00:00:01 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "BTLEAdvertisement" 
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

I didn't fully understand these results and tried several ways to solve my issue and I would very much appreciate it if someone could help me understand sleep and wake troubleshooting on the command line or from logs and settings.

Answer (score 1):

Your output from `pmset -g assertions` matches mine perfectly - nothing there would prevent a quick sleep. To dig into this deeper, I like to open a command line windows/tabs and run two commands in different shells:

```
pmset -g pslog
iostat 5
```

You can change the 5 counter - I usually use `iostat 60` or more to track long term CPU and IO trends, but sleep wake happens pretty quickly when things are running correctly with "out of the box" power settings and a fresh / new OS installation.

Here you can see the timing on the lid down and lid up:

```
2017-09-10 10:47:24 -0500 IORegisterForSystemPower: ...Sleeping...
2017-09-10 11:42:32 -0500 com.apple.system.powersources

2017-09-10 11:42:34 -0500 IORegisterForSystemPower: ...HasPoweredOn...
  Wake Reason = EC.LidOpen
  wakeType = UserActivity Assertion
2017-09-10 11:43:33 -0500 com.apple.system.powersources.timeremaining
2017-09-10 11:43:33 -0500 IOPSNotificationCreateRunLoopSource
 -InternalBattery-0 (id=4128867)    100%; discharging; 3:42 remaining present: true
```

Here you can see the jump in the `iostat 5` where the CPU was idle entering sleep (the 4.00    1  0.00   1  1 98 being low IO, and 98 % idle CPU) for the first two lines go together. Most of the values jump up the three "intervals" when I woke the lid from sleep and the CPU kicked in gear to run all the tasks needed to wake from sleep and resume apps / catch up on periodic activities missed while sleeping)

```
    4.00    1  0.00   1  1 98  2.66 1.92 1.55
    4.00    0  0.00   1  1 98  2.61 1.93 1.55
   12.02    0  0.00  16 30 54  3.60 2.14 1.63
   36.18   96  3.38  59 25 16  4.51 2.36 1.71
    6.50    2  0.01  51  9 40  4.23 2.33 1.70
```